# Calling Function Method throws "AttritubeError 'tuple' object has no attribute"

Tags: python

I am trying out the PySerial library, and I'm coming across an issue.
I am using a section of code designed to select the COM port that my Arduino is connected to. The code is:

```
import warnings
import serial
import serial.tools.list_ports

arduino_ports = [
    p.device
for p in serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
if 'Arduino' in p.description
]
if not arduino_ports:
raise IOError("No Arduino found")
if len(arduino_ports) > 1:
warnings.warn('Multiple Arduinos found - using the first')

ser = serial.Serial(arduino_ports[0])
```

When I run the code in Python (tried in 3.6 and 2.7) I get the following error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-f19fcecc00c1> in <module>()
6     p.device
7     for p in serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
----> 8     if 'Arduino' in p.description
9 ]
10 if not arduino_ports:

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'description'
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check your code indentation - it is wrong but I suspect that is due to cut and paste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be using an old version of PySerial - according to the FineManual, it seems that `list_ports.comports()` used to return a list of `(port, description, hwid)` tuple and now returns a list of `ListPortInfo` object instead:

https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/tools.html#serial.tools.list_ports.ListPortInfo

> class serial.tools.list_ports.ListPortInfo
>     This object holds information about a serial port. It supports indexed    access for backwards compatibility, as in port, desc, hwid = info.

So your options are either to change you code to work with a tuple instead:

```
arduino_ports = [
    p[0] for p in serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
    if 'Arduino' in p[1]
]
```

or, more simply, to switch to a more recent version of PySerial...

Comment: thanks, you were right on the money - I was using PySerial version 2.7. Just for documentation: I am running Anaconda, and I was able to upgrade to PySerial 3.2.1 by creating a Python 3.5 environment and upgrading via the channel 'jneines'.

Answer (score 3):

as per my knowledge i suggest you to check the contents of the variable p  in line   **if 'Arduino' in p.description**
you are getting tuple instead of object i think

Comment: Very obviously indeed.

Comment: Thanks @bruno desthuilliers

Answer (score 0):

```
serial.tools.list_ports.comports() #will return a list containing ListPortInfo objects for < version 3.0, else return tuple.
```

You are using list comprehension, so change

```
arduino_ports = [
    p.device
for p in serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
if 'Arduino' in p.description
]
```

to this,

```
import serial.tools.list_ports


ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
arduino_ports = []
for port_no, description, address in ports:
    if 'Arduino' in description:
        arduino_ports.append(port_no)
```

Comment: How is that any different? It's the same code, just in one line.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: check now, I forgot to add `list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())`

Comment: This is still doing basically the same thing (with an extra and certainly useless call to `list`), and won't solve the OP problem obviously.

Comment: And indeed serial.tools.list_ports.comports() does return a `list` already.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: for this version `serial.tools.list_ports.comports()` is returning a tuple, so I am converting to list.

Comment: @Surajano serial.tools.list_ports.comports() is returning a list (at least in the latest version), but that's totally irrelevant, first because as long as it returns an iterable - just __any__ iterable - the list expression __will__ work, and then because the OP problem is with the elements inside this iterable (cf my answer), not with the iterable itself. The error message and traceback make it quite clear FWIW.